# Disable weak cipher for Google Cloud App engine custom domain website

Tags: google-app-engine

I have set up a custom domain website using a PHP Google Cloud App engine. After some third party security testing i've been advised to disable the use of cipher suite DES-CBC3-SHA (TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA).

I'm trying to find out if its possible to disable this for a Google PHP App engine? Most of what I can find online either doesn't answer this particular question or is somewhat out of date.

I found this post useful, [Can Google App Engine Java support TLS>1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681247/can-google-app-engine-java-support-tls1-0) . This suggests it's not possible, however it doesn't actually answer the question, it just concludes that if its good enough for google it should be fine.

Comment: I am from GCP support and I have seen the issue you filed. Once it's solved and if you get to know anything else than what I have posted as an answer to this thread, please share your lesson with other Stack Overflow users here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to disable this cipher suite for a custom domain on the user end. However, it is possible to file a ticket to the GCP support and ask them to do this for your domain.

Comment: Is it possible to file a request for `app-id.appspot.com` domain or do we have to set a custom domain up?

Comment: This will work only with custom domains. Appspot.com belongs to Google and the encryption levels on that host cannot be tailored (they are the same for all the apps hosted there).