# How to update TLS version

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, reactive-programming

My Google App Engine app is using TLS version 1.0 and 1.1. Now it is recommended to update it up to 1.2. Is there any option in Google console to update it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty [similar question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404473/google-app-engine-node-js-tls-1-2) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681247/can-google-app-engine-java-support-tls1-0?rq=1) has an answer from the GCP App Engine team about TLS in general.

Summarizing, there's no option in GCP to directly update your TLS version from TLS 1.0 or 1.1, you'll have to [contact GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support/?hl=es) and request the update to TLS 1.2.