# Can I request for a TLS version upgrade if I'm on Bronze support? How can I do it?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

We have setup our api service behind an App Engine's flexible environment. We are currently on the Bronze support plan.

We were recently audited by a security contractor and one of the issues reported back to us is the fact that our service accepts older versions of TLS.

I found a couple similar questions abound this topic, namely:

- [How to update TLS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073141/how-to-update-tls-version)
- [Google App Engine Node.js TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404473/google-app-engine-node-js-tls-1-2)
- [Is there a way to customize nginx proxy in google flexible appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853799/is-there-a-way-to-customize-nginx-proxy-in-google-flexible-appengine)

So, the information I gathered by now is that cannout customize this, but I might be able to request for our load balancer to only support TLS >= 1.2. Is this info still valid as of 2020?

If it is, could someone help me figure out how? I seem to only find the chat and phone support for Billing issues. Do I need to request for someone to update our support plan for this kind of request?

Comment: I signed up for 1 month of support to do this and then cancelled it.  Not too expensive.

Comment: Yes, you are entitled to request changes on your TLS, just open a support case specifiying which Ciphers suites do you want to keep or disable